# Android Resource Unable to find resource ID #0x7f070024

Tags: java, android, android-resources

This has been the first time I've ever encountered an issue like this and I'm a bit dumbfounded by it. My problem is whenever I debug my application, everything is all fine and dandy, but as soon as I generate an apk and distribute it through crashlytics to my beta testers, all hell breaks lose and I'm thrown this `Resources$NotFoundExeption`.

I checked my `R.java` file for resource `0x7f070024` and found that it shows this:

```
public static final int common_google_play_services_unknown_issue=0x7f070024;
```

This didn't mean like much to me. I then proceeded to the other string resource error which was pointing to resource id `0x7f070036` which shows me:

```
public static final int app_name=0x7f070036;
```

I checked the usage of this variable and the only place that I'm using this string resource is inside the `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"      //**HERE**
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="blablablah"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".views.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name"> //**HERE**
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Just to complete this question, let me add my gradle files as they may be important to solving this problem:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "helpme.jesus"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0-beta.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'
    }
}
```

What am I missing? What am I doing incorrectly?

Logcat files will be added here just incase:

```
06-21 18:28:37.171 25824-25824/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: dev.helpme.jesus, PID: 25824
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f070024
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5092)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4669)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4609)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
                                                Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f070024
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:2089)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5089)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4669) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4609) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742) 



06-21 18:28:37.231 533-556/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving text 0x7f070036 in package dev.helpme.jesus
                                           android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070036
                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                                               at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1155)
                                               at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:131)
                                               at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1199)
                                               at com.android.server.am.AppErrorDialog.<init>(AppErrorDialog.java:48)
                                               at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1364)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                               at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: check your strings.xml file under res folder. can you see any line like **<string name="app_name">your app name</string>**

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I've done that numerous times.
@AshishKudale my `strings.xml` files first line is actually this:

`<string name="app_name">My app</string>`

I've also deleted the `R.java` file and rebuilt the application.

Comment: add <string name="app_name1">My app</string> to strings.xml and change app_name1 to your manifest.xml

Comment: @SathishKumarJ Okay I did just that, and now instead of having an error on my `app_name` string, it now points an error to my next string in line. This is strange.

Comment: post your .java code

Comment: @SathishKumarJ I'm sorry, which class did you want me to post? the `R.java` ?

Comment: not R.java .when your got this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115197/discussion-between-remedy-and-sathish-kumar-j).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got the similar issue with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

I tried with clean project, rebuild project, invalidate Android Studio cache. Still no luck /_\

But when I changed to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

The problem disappeared. Same code! All other settings same!

I think it was a bug in gradle build 2.2.0-alpha3

Always got problems with gradle alpha...

Comment: Yes! This was the solution. Countless hours wasted! I never thought of changing this. Thanks man!

Comment: Welcome! :)
I think people are suffering from the same problem too. Look like the next version will fix it.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210467